# jQuery only working in certain areas of Chrome App

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to create a simple serial port reader for Chrome. Nothing major, just receive the input so I can parse it. I am having some problems where jQuery is working at one point but then two lines down it is "$ undefined".

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Serial Reader",
    "description": "Read Serial barcode scanners with Google Chrome.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["background.js", "script.js", "jquery.js"],
            "transient": true
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "serial"
    ],
    "icons": { "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

Script.js:

```
    var onGetDevices = function(ports) {
      for (var i=0; iNo ports were found.");
        } else {
            //Works
            $("#portList").append("" + ports[i].path + "");
        }
      }
    };
    chrome.serial.getDevices(onGetDevices);

    var connectionId = -1;
    var portSelected = $("#portList").val(); //Returns undefined $

    var connectCallback = function() { console.log("Connected") };

    chrome.serial.connect(portSelected, null , connectCallback);

    var stringReceived = '';

    var onReceiveCallback = function(info) {
        if (info.connectionId == expectedConnectionId && info.data) {
          var str = convertArrayBufferToString(info.data);
          if (str.charAt(str.length-1) === '\n') {
            stringReceived += str.substring(0, str.length-1);
            $('#member').val(onLineReceived(stringReceived));
            stringReceived = '';
          } else {
            stringReceived += str;
          }
        }
      };

    chrome.serial.onReceive.addListener(onReceiveCallback);
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 1024,
            'height': 768
        },
        "resizable": false
    });
});
```

Window.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Serial Reader</title>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url(/images/checkin_green.png);
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><strong style="font-size: 16px;">Account Number:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="member" /></center>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <center><strong style="font-size: 16px;">Avaliable Ports:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <select id="portList"></select></center>
        <br />
        <center><span id="notFound"></span></center>

        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have been playing around with this for quite some time and cannot come up with a solution. I don't understand how it can populate the list of ports but then three lines down say that it is undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone was wondering I have tried switching back to vanilla JS and the value received is still undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the DOM is not completely ready when you query for `#portList`, so  it returns an empty list and you are trying to set the value of elements that don't exist yet.

I would suspect that the `onGetDevices` gets called after the DOM is ready, so there is no issue.  Consider wrapping DOM dependent code within `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Another issue could be that you are not querying the DOM of your extension, but rather the DOM of whatever page that triggered the extension.

Comment: I have already tried that and it gives me the $ undefined error is if it isnt loading jQuery. Will try again just for the sake of it. Its almost as if jQuery loads at one point then get unloaded somehow.

Comment: Then make sure you are importing jQuery before any other scripts are imported.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the actual manifest loading of the scripts. The manifest should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "Serial Reader",
    "description": "Read Serial barcode scanners with Google Chrome.",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js", "script.js"],
            "transient": true
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "serial"
    ],
    "icons": { "16": "icon-16.png", "128": "icon-128.png" }
}
```

With that being said I put this here just for reference sake. Thanks for the help @Wio